# Http post method Response is coming with error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, post, soap, http-post

I am executing a http post method in C# but response is coming properly except closing tag .

All nodes I am getting properly but last node before ending I am getting an error..
code at the end in response is coming like that Error :

```
<GENERATEDDATE null="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xsi:nil="true"/></APPLICATIONS></old></tuple></GetApplicationsByUserIdRespThe program 
 '[5372] CsharpToCPF.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 0 (0x0).onse>
 </SOAP:Body></SOAP:Envelope>
```

it should come like

```
<GENERATEDDATE null="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
      </APPLICATIONS>
     </old>
   </tuple>
</GetApplicationsByUserIdResponse>
```

why **"The program '[5372] CsharpToCPF.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 0 (0x0)."** is getiing appended in closing tag .

Comment: Looks like an exception thrown by the server.  Contact the server provider

Answer (score 0):

just googled the error and i found that 
**The program '[5372] CsharpToCPF.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 0 (0x0).** is not an error it indicates that program excecuted without any problem .

and it is only coming when i am displaying in console.

I am able parse the XML that is coming as response from server.

thanks